# Delete several elements from an array

Tags: ruby

I came accross the following problem: Given an `Array` named `arr` of some arbitrary objects and an array `indexes` holding some Fixnums between 0 and `arr.size`. The task is to remove the elements from `arr` at the index positions found in `indexes`.

In my concrete example, the numbers in `indexes` are all different, and sorted ascending, though I don't see how this property could help here.

I came up with the following implementations:

```
indexes.each { |i| arr.delete_at(i) }
```

or

```
arr.delete_if.with_index { |_,i| indexes.include?(i) }
```

While the first variant at least looks a bit elegant (compared to the second one), both seem to be not very efficient. Does by chance someone has an idea how to implement this in a more concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would iterate the `indexes` in *reverse* order and just delete the records at the given index:

```
indexes.sort.reverse_each { |index| arr.delete_at(index) }
```

You need to use the reverse order because after removing an element from the array at position x all indexes after that position will change.

I choose to iterate only the `indexes` array because that one is probably smaller than the `arr` array which leads to fewer steps and is, therefore, most likely more performant than iterating the whole `arr` array.

Comment: Oops, this was a bug on my side I did not notice yet! Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid making multiple calls to `Array#include?` for the `indexes`, and also avoid mutating the original `arr`, you could do:

```
arr.reject.with_index do |_, i|
  next unless indexes.first == i  
  indexes.shift # !!
end
```

This will instead however mutate the `indexes` object, so you'd need to account for that in the code.

Comment: Thanks. While it is OK to mutate the indexes, I prefer `arr` to keep its object identity. Aside from this, your solution certainly has its merits!

Comment: *"I prefer arr to keep its object identity"* -- It does; I'm not reassigning it! This method returns a *new object*. But if you want to  do `arr = arr.reject.with_index ....` then I agree, you might as well just mutate the value instead.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing that as follows.

```
arr = [1, 4, 6, 2, 7, 3]
indices_to_remove = [4, 0, 3]
```

```
arr.values_at((0..arr.size-1).to_a - indices_to_remove)
  #=> [4, 6, 3]
```

This does not mutate `arr`. To modify `arr` in place write

```
arr.replace(arr.values_at((0..arr.size-1).to_a - indices_to_remove))
```

See [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at), [Array#-](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) and [Array#replace](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-replace).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to delete array element.

If you don't want to modify original array **arr**

```
arr.reject.with_index { |element, i| indexes.include? i }
```

If you want to modify original array **arr**

```
arr.reject!.with_index { |element, i| indexes.include? i }
```

Please refer example below

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
indexes = [1, 3]

arr.reject.with_index { |element, i| indexes.include? i }
```

This will return [1, 3, 5] deleting 1st and 3rd element of array and array **arr** will be remains same as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

```
arr.reject!.with_index { |element, i| indexes.include? i }
```

This will return [1, 3, 5] deleting 1st and 3rd element of array again but array **arr** will be modify to [1, 3, 5]

Comment: `reject!` virtually the same as my second solution. I was also considering `reject!`; the effect is, for my purpose, the same as `delete_if`, but I found a thread on [so] which diescussed benchmarks, and found `delete_if` slightly faster.